# How to secure Outlook [Resolved]

Tags: email

I was curious on some best practices for securing Outlook against hackers.

The data transmitted between the email server and client are almost always encrypted these days but I haven't seen a great deal of security when the mail actually is on the local machine. If someone were to gain access to your machine rather it be Outlook or Thunderbird - they now also have access to any email service you're logged into.

The actual stored archives can be password protected but that does nothing for active mail within the inbox.

My question is, how does one secure email on the actual machine from prying eyes?

And yeah, I know - unless it's PGP - email isn't secure.

Edit: Correction - PGP isn't secure either one it's 'open'/decrypted on the local machine.

Solution: TL;DR - No direct solution other than encrypting drive it's on.

I asked on Microsoft forums and was directed to Symantec.. and was basically told that there is no solution to lock Outlook itself or individual emails but rather rely on Bitlocker.

Comment: How to you anticipate that something like this would work? The e-mail HAS to be decrypted in order for the end-user to be able to work with it, so if it's not at rest it can't be encrypted.

Comment: I said that already lol... it's possible to encapsulate operating systems with encryption. It's also possible to keep an email client using PGP with password protection where the actual client is encrypted until unlocked.